# How to push Docker image to self-hosted Artifactory?

Tags: docker, artifactory

Just created a self-hosted Artifactory running on AWS. I can reach the Artifactory UI at 10.100.10.100:8082 (not the real address). I setup a Docker repo, and the URL showing in the UI for the repo is http://10.100.10.100:8082/artifactory/myrepo/. The Docker login command was successful, but the Docker push won't work. I tried tagging the image as 10.100.10.100:8082/artifactory/myrepo, but after retrying several times, I get `unknown: not found`. I tried tagging with the entire URl including the `http://` but it won't accept that as a tag name. What is the proper syntax for pushing a tagged image to my self-hosted Artifactory?

Comment: It's not the answer of your question, but as a suggestion, while there is AWS ECR, in my opinion, there is no need to create self hosted registry. Because maintaining will be relatively harder in the future. Disk space problems etc. AWS ECR is providing all thing that you expect from a registry. Also very cheap. If you are not aware of that, you can consider it. 

https://aws.amazon.com/ecr/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, Artifactory as Docker registry is configured with Repository path method. which means, that for pulling and pushing docker images, you will need to append the url with repository key and image name and tag.

For example:

Assuming the docker image is alpine and the tag is latest.
The Artifactory docker repository is of type local and the repository key is docker-local.

Back to the example above,

```
docker login 10.100.10.100:8081
docker tag <alpine:latest-image_id> 10.100.10.100:8081/docker-local/alpine:latest
docker push 10.100.10.100:8081/docker-local/alpine:latest
docker pull 10.100.10.100:8081/docker-local/alpine
```

A few side notes:

1. In version 7.x the web UI is accessible via port 8082 and Artifactory’s service is still using port 8081
2. You might need to add the ip address:port of the running Artifactory to the docker daemon configuration file. As follows:

   insecure-registries": [
   "10.100.10.100:8081"
   ]

For further read regarding Repository Path Method please refer to: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Getting+Started+with+Artifactory+as+a+Docker+Registry#GettingStartedwithArtifactoryasaDockerRegistry-TheRepositoryPathMethod

Answer (score 5):

To complement Tom.A's excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71132841/11942268), I want to highlight that you have to push to the *correct* URL.

If your repo URL (a. k. a. "URL to file" in Artifactory) looks like this:

```
http://10.100.10.100:8082/artifactory/myrepo/
```

You have to push to:

```
10.100.10.100:8082/myrepo/myimage:mytag
```

So you have to remove `artifactory` from the URL and tag your images accordingly.